# How to do a continual loop for my traffic light sequence javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to do a traffic light sequence which runs on a timed basis automatically without user input. I have got the code working now, but it only runs through once and then stops. So how can I change this so it keeps going?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var images = new Array()
            images[0] = "image2.jpg";
            images[1] = "image3.jpg";
            images[2] = "image4.jpg";
            setInterval("changeImage()", 3000);
            var x=0;

            function changeImage() {
                document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]
                x++;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="img" src="image1.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note: don't use a string for `setInterval` but write `setInterval(changeImage, 3000);` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the remainder assignment [`%=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Remainder_assignment) to the counter with the length of the array.

```
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
    x++;
    x %= images.length;
}
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner: `x = (x + 1) % images.length;`

Comment: @t.niese & Nina: Don't know what I was thinking. There's another idiom where you don't need the parens, but this is clearly not it. Thanks for flagging it up. (Edit: I remembered: The other idiom I was mixing it up with is for 1-based counters, because of course in that case we want the `%` first: `n = n % inclusiveMax + 1`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, maybe the rule of thumb may help remainder is (the same precedence) as division.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Oh, I know. Just a mental hiccup. :-)

Comment: @NinaScholz I've seen that you edited the answer to images.length . it also works as x %=3

Comment: @DaniM, that's right, but if you change the array and adds or deletes one color, then you have to change the value too.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    var images = new Array()
    images[0] = "image1.jpg";
    images[1] = "image2.jpg";
    images[2] = "image3.jpg";
    images[3] = "image4.jpg";
    setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
    var x=0;

    function changeImage() {
        document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]
        x++;
        x %= images.length;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img id="img" src="image1.jpg">
    </body>
    </html> 
Here is my updated code for interest.